# Alter column ignoring dependent views

Tags: postgresql

I have column `column` with `character varying(20)` type, i want to increase it to `50`

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE character varying(50);
```

I get an error that `view view_name depends on column "column"`. I wonder how can i alter column without dropping and recreating about 10 depending views?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found on this [blog](http://mwenus.blogspot.nl/2014/04/postgresql-how-to-handle-table-and-view.html)

> PostgreSQL is very restrictive when it comes to modifying existing
>   objects. Very often when you try to ALTER TABLE or REPLACE VIEW it
>   tells you that you cannot do it, because there's another object
>   (typically a view or materialized view), which depends on the one you
>   want to modify. It seems that the only solution is to DROP dependent
>   objects, make desired changes to the target object and then recreate
>   dropped objects.
>
> It is tedious and cumbersome, because those dependent objects can have
>   further dependencies, which also may have other dependencies and so
>   on. I created [utility functions](https://gist.github.com/mateuszwenus/11187288) which can help in such situations.
>
> The usage is very simple - you just have to call:
>
> `select deps_save_and_drop_dependencies(p_schema_name, p_object_name);`
>
> You
>   have to pass two arguments: the name of the schema and the name of the
>   object in that schema. This object can be a table, a view or a
>   materialized view. The function will drop all views and materialized
>   views dependent on `p_schema_name.p_object_name` and save DDL which
>   restores them in a helper table.
>
> When you want to restore those dropped objects (for example when you
>   are done modyfing `p_schema_name.p_object_name`), you just need to make
>   another simple call:
>
> `select deps_restore_dependencies(p_schema_name,p_object_name);`
>
> and the dropped objects will be recreated.
>
> These functions take care about:
>
> - dependencies hierarchy
> - proper order of dropping and creating views/materialized views across hierarchy
> - restoring comments and grants on views/materialized views
>
> Click [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e1e32/1)
>   for a working sqlfiddle example or check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mateuszwenus/11187288) for a complete
>   source code

Comment: This doesn't create indexes on the views.

Comment: There's a refactoring and repo-ising that does (and more): https://github.com/rvkulikov/pg-deps-management

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, but a [TODO feature](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Views_and_Rules). You should create a script that is able to handle such a thing as simple view creations.